# Is it fine to write "skip() unless ok()" with Test::More?

Tags: perl, tap, test-more

I've gone through the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) and can't find a definitive answer to my query.

In a lot of my tests, the execution of a **`SKIP`** block is conditional to the success of a prior test.

So, for example, this what I write:

```
ok( @results > $threshold , 'Threshold met' );

SKIP: {
        skip 'due to insufficient results', 3
          unless @results > $threshold;
        # ...
}
```

If my test changes, I don't want to have to change two locations, so I'd like a DRY-er equivalent:

```
SKIP: {
        skip 'due to insufficient results', 3
          unless ok( @results > $threshold , 'Threshold met' );
        # ...
}
```

My initial tests suggest that the two snippets are equivalent.

However, something in the documentation caught my eye:

> Each `SKIP` block must have the label `SKIP`, or `Test::More` can't work its magic.

My concern here is that the magic may spill over to the `ok()` as it is now inside the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: "Each `SKIP` block must have the label `SKIP`, or `Test::More` can't work its magic." The concern was that the magic would spill over to the `ok()` (It's inside the block)

Comment: `skip` does `last SKIP;`. `ok` doesn't.